# How to connect two objects of two models together in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

This is my models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    release_time = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Ticket(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    #movie_time = models.ForeignKey(Movie.release_time, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In class Ticket, I want to get get two objects from the Movie class, which are the `title` and the `release_time`. I managed to get one of them using `__str__(self)` function, I want  `Movie.title` in the `movie` variable and also I need the selected Movie objects's `release_time` in the `movie_time` variable(I've written the pseudocode of what I want in the commented line).

How can I do the same?

Any help will be Appreciated!

Comment: It's sufficient to just have the `Movie` model as a `ForeignKey` on your `Ticket` model. And then in your views you have access to all the fields.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks! I'll try that and let you know ASAP